# list all table elements and count() even if count is 0

Tags: sql, count

Suppose the following tables:

```
table book(
  id,
  title,
  deleted
)
table invoice(
  id,
  book_id,
  settled
)
```

I need a list off all the books and the number of settled invoices for each book.

I tried this:

```
select book.id, title, count(invoice.id)
from book LEFT OUTER JOIN invoice ON book.id=invoice.book_id
where deleted=0
    and settled=1
group by book.id
```

This works only if a book has at least 1 settled invoice or if it doesn't have any invoce at all. However it fails when a book has unsettled invoices and it doesn't have any settled invoice.

Any idea how to query it ?

Answer (score 2):

The following will list all books, but only join and count settled invoices.

```
SELECT 
    b.id, b.title, COUNT(i.id) AS settled
FROM 
    book b
LEFT JOIN invoice i
    ON b.id = i.book_id 
    AND i.settled = 1
WHERE 
    b.deleted = 0
GROUP BY
    b.id
```

Answer (score 1):

The condition `and settled = 1` on your `WHERE` is effectively turning your `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`. You can add a `CASE` expression to your `COUNT`:

```
SELECT  b.id, 
        b.title, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN i.settled = 1 THEN 1 END)
FROM book b
LEFT JOIN invoice i
    ON b.id = i.book_id
WHERE b.deleted=0
GROUP BY b.id;
```

Or use the `LEFT JOIN` with the invoice table already filtered:

```
SELECT  b.id, 
        b.title, 
        COUNT(i.id)
FROM book b
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT *
            FROM invoice
            WHERE settled = 1) i
    ON b.id = i.book_id
WHERE b.deleted=0
GROUP BY b.id;
```

Comment: Is there a benefit to using a sub-query on the `LEFT JOIN`, instead of adding the  `settled = 1` as a second join condition?

Comment: @fubar none, it's the same. I just find it to be clearer what the intention is

Comment: Thank you @Lamak, both of your solutions work perfect !